# How to access req body as json?

Tags: express

In an Express4 app, I already did:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

then in the post method, I access req.body:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.body)
   res.json({ status: true })
});
```

it is just a string, not a json:

```
POST /email?name=test&email=abc@abc.com
```

Why?

Comment: The POST request you quoted is missing its body entirely.

Comment: If you were getting JSON then it **should** be a string. If you were POSTing a JSON body (and there is no sign that you are) then I would expect that code to parse it and present you with a JavaScript object as the value of `req.body`.

Comment: all are correct, I did not post a x-www-form-urlencoded data

Comment: You didn't post *anything*.